# TabBarController instance Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller, swift2

I am trying to Compile my app again now that Swift 2 is out and the thing is I am having an error with `TabBarController` instances.

I am declaring the instances in vars in order to use methods from anothers `ViewControllers`.

Here it's my code:

```
let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers 
let listViewController = barViewControllers![2].viewControllers![0] as! dbViewController //The [2] is because it's the third TabBar and the [0] it's because It's embebed in a NavigationController.
let calendarViewController = barViewControllers![1] as! CalendarViewController
```

In the second line Im having the following error:

```
UIViewController does not have a member named "viewControllers"
```

Anybody could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the property `viewControllers` of the type `UIViewController`, which it doesn't have. `viewControllers` is a property on a `UITabBarController`, but `viewControllers` returns an array of `UIViewController`.

Cast `viewControllers` to an array of `UITabBarController` (or only the item you extract) to access it's `viewController` property.

Like this:

```
let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers as! [UITabBarController]
```

Or this:

```
let listViewController = (barViewControllers![2] as! UITabBarController).viewControllers![0] as! dbViewController
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! Now it's working and I have understood the problem :)